# NSIS - Define InstallDir depending on FileExists

Tags: nsis

What I want to do with this script is to copy a file in a folder who already exists.
But it can be at the root (C:) or in the program files.

There what I want, but this script doesn’t work:

```
  ${If} ${FileExists} "C:\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\Profiles"
    InstallDir "C:\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\Profiles"
  ${ElseIf} ${FileExists} "$PROGRAMFileS\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\Profiles"
    InstallDir "$PROGRAMFileS\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\Profiles"
  ${EndIf}
```

Someone can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set $instdir in .onInit with StrCpy:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

InstallDir "C:\Something\something" ; Used if neither of the files exist.

Function .onInit
${If} ${FileExists} "C:\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\Profiles"
  StrCpy $InstDir "C:\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\Profiles"
${ElseIf} ${FileExists} "$ProgramFiles\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\Profiles"
  StrCpy $InstDir "$ProgramFiles\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\Profiles"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: That is, something like: `strCpy $INSTDIR "C:\Your\Path"` in a `Function .onInit` block.